# Question about furiten definition regarding winning tile in riichi mahjong

Tags: riichi-mahjong

relatively new riichi mahjong player here. I haven't had this situation happen to myself before, but I'm curious about how the rules apply in this situation:

1. Suppose I'm trying to go for tanyao (I know some rulesets don't allow tanyao in open hands - let's suppose my current ruleset does allow for it), and have already called the following melds: 6-7-8, 3-4-5, and 4-5-6 (the suits don't really matter for this hypothetical, I'm just establishing that my hand is open here)
2. I currently have 4 non-melded tiles in my hand: **a 2 and 3 of some suit, say dots**, and a pair of 8s (again, for this pair, the suits don't matter)
3. **My discard pile currently has a 1-dot (but does NOT have a 4-dot)**.

My question is, according to the wiki:

[image]

From the first condition, it says a **winning** tile. Does this mean the tile MUST yield at least one yaku? That is, in my above situation, **would I or would I not be in furiten due to the one dot in my discard pile**? I cannot form a hand with a valid yaku if I were to draw or call on a 1-dot, because tanyao forbids terminals.

**My assumption** is that because 1-dot does not enable a hand that has at least one yaku, it does not count as a "winning tile" - therefore, my hand would not be in furiten. However, I am not sure and would like some feedback here. Also, I provided a specific situation above, but I suppose my question also extends to all furiten-related circumstances where a tile that could form a valid meld exists in my discard but which cannot provide any yaku.